# Executing bound std::function throws std::bad_function_call

Tags: c++, runtime-error, function-calls, std-function, stdbind

I want to bind a member function to a `std::function<void(void)>`. I heard that member functions take one extra parameter which is the instance pointer. Therefore I call `std::bind(&Class::Function, this, parameter)` but when I execute the function object, it throws a runtime error.

> Unhandled exception at at 0x748D4B32 in Application.exe: Microsoft C++
>   exception: std::bad_function_call at memory location 0x0114F4E8.

The parameter is a pointer to one of my own `struct`s. How am I doing wrong? What additional information do you need?

Update: Here is my code.

```
class ModuleRenderer
{
    struct Pass{ std::function<void()> Function; /* many more members... */ };
    std::vector<std::pair<std::string, Pass>> passes;

    enum Drawfunc{ FORMS, SKY, LIGHTS, QUAD, SCREEN };
    void AddPass(std::string Name, Drawfunc Function)
    {
        Pass pass;
        // set some of the members
        // ...

        passes.push_back(std::make_pair(Name, pass));
        Pass *pointer = &(passes.back().second);

        switch (Function)
        {
        case FORMS:
            pointer->Function = std::bind(&ModuleRenderer::DrawForms, this, pointer);
            break;

            // analogeously for the other cases
            // ...
        }
    }

    void DrawForms(Pass *pass)
    {
        // ...
    }

    // is called consecutively after adding all passes
    void Update()
    {
        for(auto i : passes)
            // some initializing based on members of pass
            i.Function();
    }
};
```

Comment: How about showing us the code that's throwing this exception? Please include the lines where you assign the member function pointer to the `std::function`. `bad_function_call` is thrown when you attempt to invoke an `std::function` that has no target, so the binding code is relevant.

Comment: @Praetorian I haven't used `std::bind` before, so I didn't knew what code is important. And there is a lot of code in my project. But thanks to you comment, I could provide the needed pieces of my code. I updated my question.

Comment: `for(auto i : passes)` will copy each element of `passes` into `i`  - does `Pass` have a sane copy constructor?

Comment: @Casey `Pass` has no explicit copy constructor. It has no member functions at all.

Comment: `Pass *pointer = &(passes.back().second);` - the pointer will become invalid when you push_back and the vector's underlying storage is reallocated.

Comment: @molbdnilo Sounds like you found the problem. Do you know how to solve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of different issues have been pointed out in the comments above. To resolve these, try making the following changes to your code:

```
struct Pass{ std::function<void(Pass *)> Function; /* ... */ };

// ...

case FORMS:
  pointer->Function = 
      std::bind(&ModuleRenderer::DrawForms, this, std::placeholders::_1);
  break;
```

Do not bind the `Pass *` to the function call just yet, because, as [@molbdnilo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/404970/molbdnilo) points out, that pointer will become invalid when you call `AddPass()` multiple times and the vector is resized.

Since the `std::function` now takes a `Pass *`, you need to supply the correct pointer when you invoke it.

```
void Update()
{
    for(auto& i : passes) { // <-- take a reference, don't copy
        // some initializing based on members of pass
        i.Function( &i );   // pass Pass * to the function
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
passes.push_back(std::make_pair(Name, pass));
Pass *pointer = &(passes.back().second);
```

That `pointer` will become invalid when you later `push_back` and the vector grows.

You could avoid pointers altogether and pass the index of the corresponding object instead of a pointer.

```
pointer->Function = std::bind(&ModuleRenderer::DrawForms, this, passes.size() - 1);

// ...

void DrawForms(size_t i)
{
    Pass& pass = passes[i].second;
    // Handle as before...
}
```

Comment: Nice idea to use the index.